# resizableImageWithCapInsets on UISlider gets distorted in iOS 6 and up

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uikit, uislider

I have a `UISlider` that I want to put a custom created `UIImage` on to be stretched. I create it like this:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width * difference, image.size.height)];
    iv.backgroundColor = [BSFunctions getColorFromHex:@"f7f8fa"];
    iv.image = cappedImage;
    [self addSubview:iv];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (iv.frame.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [iv.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [iv removeFromSuperview];

    return img;
```

I can confirm that the image is created right and it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I put it to a slider and the image starts to stretch, it looks like this:
[image]

The way I add it to the slider is the following:

```
UIImage *newImage = [self imageStretchedOnLeft];
    UIImage *rightStretchImage = [newImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, newImage.size.width - 2, 0, 0)];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:rightStretchImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It used to be working a couple of builds ago and I was not touching anything when it suddenly stopped to work. What's even more surprising, `UISlider` works like it should on iOS 5.1 simulator and therefore on iOS 5! This whole thing is driving me crazy and I don't know how to even approach it. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm creating an app for iOS 5 and up and testing it on iOS 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem like this:

```
if (iosVersion < 6.0){
    rightStretchImage = [newImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, newImage.size.width - 2, 0, 0)];
}else{
    rightStretchImage = [newImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, newImage.size.width - 2, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
}
```